# flutter: why input content disappear when textField lose the focus?

Tags: flutter, dart

I put a `textField` with a `clear button` and `hintText` in a `Container`. My hope is when the `textField` has the focus, the `clear button` will appear, and when losing the focus, the button disappears. But when I put away the keyboard(the `textField` lose the focus), the input content and the `hintText` disappear. So what's wrong?

```
Container(
                      width: 330,
                      height: 40,
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: inputController,
                        focusNode: focusNode,
                        style: MyTextStyle.level9,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'hint text',
                          hintStyle: MyTextStyle.grey,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          suffixIcon: focusNode.hasFocus ? IconButton(
                            icon: MyIcon.CloseIcon,
                            onPressed: () {
                              inputController.clear();
                            }
                          ) : Container(),
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: MyColor.MidGray,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Container` widget you used for the `suffixIcon` is taking up all the available space, using a `SizedBox` widget works well and produces the expected behaviour.

I added an example using your code:

```dart
Container(
        width: 330,
        height: 40,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: TextField(
          controller: inputController,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          style: MyTextStyle.level9,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'hint text',
            hintStyle: MyTextStyle.grey,
            border: InputBorder.none,
            suffixIcon: focusNode.hasFocus
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: MyIcon.CloseIcon,
                    onPressed: () {
                      inputController.clear();
                    })
                // use a SizedBox widget instead
                : SizedBox.shrink(),
            filled: true,
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: MyColor.MidGray,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Also, I add a `width: 0` to `Container` then works. Thank you very much.